# How to make a function that uses incomplete type objects

Tags: c++, templates, types

I want to make a `class one` that can build up `class two` by `func1`.
I have two type of class overloading. The primary template class, and the overloading template specialization class.
Primary `class one` is fine. But `class one<void>` can not implement `func1`.
The compiler complains `return type 'class two<void>' is incomplete`, `aggregate 'two<void> t' has incomplete type and cannot be defined`, and `two<void> used in a nested specifier, stdx::shared_future<void>::num_copies_ = 2;`.
What can I do to make a one version of `func1`?
Thank you.

```cpp
template<class T2>
class two;
template<>
class two<void>;

template<class T1>
class one 
{
    // ...
    public:
    two<T1> func1()
    {
        two<T1> t;
        two<T1>::two__ = 1;
        //...
        // manipulation of obj t.
        //...
        return t;
    }
    // ...
};

template<>
class one<void>
{
    // ...
    public:
    two<void> func1()
    {
        two<void> t;
        two<void>::two__ = 1;
        //...
        // manipulation of obj t.
        //...
        return t;
    }
    // ...
};

template<class T2>
class two 
{
    static int two__;
    // definition of two 
};

template<>
class two<void>
{
    public:
    static int two__;
    // definition of two<void>
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid errors related to incomplete types the `one::func1` method can be defined after `two`. It can be declared like this:

```
template<>
class one<void> {
public:
    two<void> func1();
};
```

And then, after `two` has been defined:

```
two<void> one<void>::func1() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It works. But I want to clearify a little. I must define `two` after `one` because `two` uses `one` as well. That is why I declare `two` before definition of `one`. Thank you.

Comment: @yuewang Nothing in this answer prevents that.  Apply the same technique.